# VBA workbook reference toggle

Tags: excel, vba

I have a master workbooks and summary workbook. The summary workbook is referenced via:

```
Set SummaryTemplate = ActiveWorkBook
```

The summary workbook is middle layer which I never save.

Is there a way to reference the SummaryTemplate in another macro?

Answer (score 1):

Just `Dim` SummaryTemplate **above** the subs:

```
Dim SummaryTemplate As Workbook

Sub MAIN()
    Set SummaryTemplate = ActiveWorkbook
    Call LittleGuy
End Sub

Sub LittleGuy()
    MsgBox SummaryTemplate.Name
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks, i shoudl have clarified i want to be able to do this between 2 different modules. is ther a way to do this?

Comment: @michaelBard  Try `Public SummaryTemplate as Workbook` .............tell me what happens